# Supabase: Filter data with join and logical 'OR'

Tags: javascript, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I'm using Supabase as a database and trying to implement a full-text search.

My example setup is quite simple, I have two tables:

**items**

```
+----+-----------+-----------------+
| id | name      | manufacturer_id |
+----+-----------+-----------------+
| 1  | Notebook  | 1               |
+----+-----------+-----------------+
| 2  | Mouse     | 2               |
+----+-----------+-----------------+
```

**manufacturers**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Apple     |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Microsoft |
+----+-----------+
```

**My goal:** search for item names or manufacturer names and always receive the respective `items`. Searching for 'Apple' would return all items whose manufacturers name contain this phrase. Searching for 'Notebook' would return all items with this name.

(*I simplified this example by using exact matches because this is not the problem I'm stuck with*).

My current approach is the following:

```
let keyword = 'Apple';

supabase
  .from('items')
  .select('*, manufacturers!inner(*)')
  .or(`name.eq.${term}`)
  .or(`name.eq.${term}`, { foreignTable: 'manufacturers' })
```

Although this query does not return anything.

If I remove `.or('name.eq.${term}')` it return the correct item. Same if I remove the second `.or()` and use an item name as my keyword.

I simply can't find a way to combine two OR operators. I also tried multiple `filter()` queries but was not successfully.

EDIT:
The (working) SQL syntax would be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
   JOIN manufacturers ON items.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
   WHERE items.name = 'Apple' OR manufacturers.name = 'Apple'
```

Does anyone have an approach on how to do that with the Supabase JavaScript SDK? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392789/postgres-function-where-clause-aggregation-with-for-loop/74394984?noredirect=1#comment131335241_74394984 for rpc solution

Answer (score 1):

You can't OR combine a foreign table(`manufacturers`) condition with a parent table(`items`) condition directly through the JS SDK.

(More details about why [here](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/discussions/2014#discussioncomment-1598919))

However you can create a function wrapping your query and use rpc to get it:

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc

Comment: any other suggestion but rpc? I need to build generic query with unknown columns and filters