# Postgres function: where clause aggregation with for loop

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I created a postgres function that receives an array of text as parameter. For each text in the array I want to check if any of the the columns in the query match it with like clause.

Is it possible to aggregate where clause like this in a for loop?

For example for clarification, I have the above tables:

```
lessons

+----+-----------+-----------------+
| id | name      | teacher_id      |
+----+-----------+-----------------+
| 1  | English   | 1               |
+----+-----------+-----------------+
| 2  | Spanish   | 2               |
+----+-----------+-----------------+
Teachers

+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Teacher 1 |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Teacher 2 |
+----+-----------+
```

I want to get as parameters text[] and for each text in the array I want to execute an OR clause between the column in both tables and return array of jsons(`[{"id": 1, "teacher": {"id":1, "name": "Teacher1"}}]`)

For example if the parameters are ["lish", "er"] I want it to execute:

```
where 
   lessons.name like '%lish%' or teachers.name like '%lish%'
and
   lessons.name like '%er%' or teachers.name like '%er%'
```

teacher with id 1 will return.

The thing is I don't know in advance the parameters so this is why I assume I need a FOR loop.

Also, how to I make the query to return an array of jsons that each teacher will be an inner json object of each lesson?

Would appreciate some examples if so. Thank you!

Comment: your question is incomplete for a good understanding. Please update it with the query and its columns you talk about, and with an example of the result you want to achieve.

Comment: With examples it's hard to imagine what you need, but it's unlikely that you need a loop.

Comment: hope now it will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop-like function such as in plpgsql to get your expected result. A basic `sql` query will be more efficient :

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, t.id, t.name
  FROM lessons AS l
 INNER JOIN teachers AS t
    ON t.id = l.teacher_id
 INNER JOIN unnest( array['lish', 'er']) AS c(cond)
    ON t.name ~ c.cond OR l.name ~ c.cond
 GROUP BY l.id, l.name, t.id, t.name
HAVING count(*) = array_length(array['lish','er'], 1)
```

- First this query joins both tables `lessons` and `teachers` with a
  match on `teacher_id`.
- Then it is joined with every element of the
  input array through the `unnest` function.
- For each row of the joined tables `lessons` and `teachers`, both names are compared to the input array element using the regular expression `~` operator.
- Then the selected rows are grouped together so that to count the number of
  rows which match with all the array elements. This check is performed
  in the `HAVING` clause where `count(*)` is the number of resulting
  rows for the same (lessons.id, teachers.id) tuple and it  is compared
  to the total number of elements in the array with the `array_length` function..

If you want to return an array of jsonb, just format the query result :

```
SELECT json_agg(c.result)
  FROM (
SELECT (json_build_object('lesson_id', l.id, 'lesson_name',l.name, 'teacher', json_build_object('teacher_id', t.id, 'teacher_name', t.name))) AS result
  FROM lessons AS l
 INNER JOIN teachers AS t
    ON t.id = l.teacher_id
 INNER JOIN unnest( array['lish', 'er']) AS c(cond)
    ON t.name ~ c.cond OR l.name ~ c.cond
 GROUP BY l.id, l.name, t.id, t.name
HAVING count(*) = array_length(array['lish','er'], 1)) AS c
```

see the full test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zyfYj55K)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It works. Since this is a postgres function, what is the return type of it?

Comment: the return type depends on the format of the columns in the SELECT clause. In the first query it is a record, in the second query it is a json type.

Comment: it seems that it doesn't make AND between the array values. Look at https://dbfiddle.uk/FJi54tW2

Comment: The `AND` is performed through the `HAVING` clause which checks that the number of rows  for a given tuple (lesson, teacher) and which match with the array elements equals the total number of elements in the array.

Comment: So why in the dbfiddle I sent it doesn’t work as expected ? It was supposed to return empty array because there is no ‘2’ in the teacher 1 with English name

Comment: For me the dbfiddle works as expected : with the data set you provided there is only teacher wit id = 1 and lesson with id = 1 which match with both key words 'lish' and 'er'

Comment: In the dbfiddle I provided there is no lesson with teacher that match both keys ‘En’ and ‘2’, but is still returned lesson with id 1

Comment: Yes you're right, I made a mistake considering in the `HAVING` clause that `max(c.id)` would correspond to the length of the array, but it is not because this clause applies after the `GROUP BY` clause, so it is just equal to the highest rank of the element in the array which match with lesson_id or with teacher_id. You have to put the number of elements in the array instead of max(c.id)`. I've updated the answer and the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zyfYj55K) accordingly.